# How to send a file to another computer with bash script?

Tags: macos, mac, bash, scp, sftp

I know that you could use sftp to send a file, from the command line - but I don't know how to do this in a .sh file. Is there a way to do this is one line, or many lines, as long as it's possible in a bash file.
I already know how to do this for getting files, but not for sending them.
I also need to send it to a specific directory.

Comment: Does your destination require a password to be input?

Comment: Yes, but if the solution uses ssh I can use sshpass to supply the password as a variable @MMB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desired .sh file should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp /local/file user@remotehost:/path/to/directory
```

[Examples of scp command](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

Make sure that the .sh file is executable, otherwise use `chmod` command.

Comment: your file also needs to be executable. When you run ls -l you should see x for executable permission. You can change permissions using chmod.

Comment: @yohann.martineau when I try this, I get the error:                cp: /filetransfer.sh: Permission denied
cp: /mainmini@192.168.1.65: Permission denied

Comment: let's try scp filetransfer.sh mainmini@192.168.1.65:/ (with a column between ip address and path)

Comment: @yohann.martineau Now I get the error: scp: /filetransfer.sh: Permission denied

Comment: take care you may not have permissions to modify root path. I'm not a mac expert, but I think you should try with /tmp or /Users/mainmini.

Comment: @JaroslavSvestka Note that you could've just posted your own answer and got the reputation for it. Yohann, next time please edit your post instead of just leaving a comment below it. Thanks.

Comment: @yohann.martineau Nope, `scp` doesn't rely on `sftp`.  They both use the `ssh` protocol for transport, but they are different.  To see this, disable `sftp-server` in your `sshd_config`.  You would no longer be able to run `sftp` against that machine, but `scp` will run just fine.

Comment: @lcd047: you're right, sorry. I'll update my comment. But I think scp is what Jacob_ was looking for.

Comment: The command `scp filetransfer.sh mainmini@192.168.1.65: ` will copy the file `filetransfer.sh` in the home directory of the user `mainmini`. Given the correct password is usually allowed. Instead `scp filetransfer.sh mainmini@192.168.1.65:/ ` will try to copy the file `filetransfer.sh` in the root `/`, usually not allowed for a not privileged user.